# Why my program is getting crashed while implementing the list in C?

Tags: c, list, data-structures

When I tried to implement a list as follows in C. My program is getting crashed in the middle way. I think there is a problem while passing values to the **InsertList** function in Main(). Can someone explain what is the problem in my main function. Are my DeleteList,RetrieveList functions correct?. Are there any mistakes while passing arguments to those functions?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20
#define EMPTY -1
#define FULL MAX-1

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} Boolean;
typedef char ListEntry;
typedef int Position;
typedef struct list
{
    int count;
    ListEntry entry[MAX];
}List;

void CreateList(List *l)
{
    l->count=-1;
}

Boolean IsListEmpty(List *l)
{
    return (l->count==EMPTY);
}

Boolean IsListFull(List *l)
{
    return (l->count==FULL);
}

int ListSize(List *l)
{
    return (l->count);
}

void InsertLast(ListEntry x,List *l)
{
    if(IsListFull(l))
        printf("Try to insert to full list\n");
    else
    {
        l->entry[l->count]=x;
        l->count++;
        printf("The entered element at last is %d\n", x);
    }
}

void InsertList(Position p,ListEntry x,List *l)
{
    if(IsListFull(l))
        printf("Try to insert to full list\n");
    else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))
        printf("Try to insert to a position not in list\n");
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=ListSize(l)-1;i>=p;i--)
            l->entry[i+1]=l->entry[i];
        //l->entry[p-1]=x;
        l->count++;
    }
}

void ReplaceList(Position p,ListEntry x,List *l)
{
    if(IsListFull(l))
        printf("Try to replace to full list\n");
    else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))
        printf("Try to replace a position not in list\n");
    else
        l->entry[p-1]=x;
}

void DeleteList(Position p,List *l)
{
    int i;
    if(IsListEmpty(l))
        printf("Try to delete from a empty list\n");
    else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))
        printf("Try to delete a position not in list\n");
    else
    {
        ListEntry x=l->entry[p-1];
        for(i=p-1;i<ListSize(l);i++)
            l->entry[i]=l->entry[i+1];
        l->count--;
        printf("Deleted element is %d", x);
    }
}

void RetrieveList(Position p,List *l)
{
    if(IsListEmpty(l))
        printf("Try to retrieve from a empty list\n");
    else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))
        printf("Try to retrieve a position not in list\n");
    else{
        ListEntry x=l->entry[p];
    printf("Retrieved element is: %d", x);
    }
}
```

My main() function is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    List l;
    CreateList(&l);
    DeleteList(2,&l);
    InsertLast(5,&l);
    InsertLast(6,&l);
    InsertList(1,3,&l);
    InsertList(2,2,&l);
    InsertList(3,1,&l);
    RetrieveList(3,&l);
    DeleteList(2,&l);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use the `count` member as index for accessing the `entry` array. Make sure the index is in the range 0..(MAX-1). I suggest to set `EMPTY` to zero. And use this EMPTY as the initialization value in `CreateList`.

Comment: Try setting `l->count = 0;` in `CreateList` (not `-1`). Also change `EMPTY` to `0` and `FULL` to `MAX`.

Comment: For an empty list, the number of entries are zero, so *count* should be zero.

Comment: @harper Is my ListSize() function correct?

Comment: I can't tell you if `ListSize()` is correct. It depends on what you expect. `ListSize()` returns 0 if no item is in the list and 1 more for each item. This looks plausible. For a serious use of that set of functions I would add a comment to each function what (but not how) it does and what a caller should expect. That's called interface documentation. You can say a function is correct if the implementation fulfills the behavior described in the interface documentation. If `ListSize`shall give information about the max. possible items in the list, it's incorrect.

Comment: @harper when I try to insert elements using `InsertList()` function it says **Try to insert to a position not in list** that means List size is not increasing. What should I do?

Comment: If nothing could inserted, the `ListSize()` result should not change. Use the correct parameters for `InsertList()`. If you have problems, ask a new question. This would allow information *what* you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `CreateList` you set `l->count = -1`, then when you call `InsertLast` you try to access `l->entry[-1]` so you have a segmentation fault

```c
#define EMPTY 0

void CreateList(List *l)
{
    l->count=EMPTY;
}
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you @MickaelB.  Is my RetrieveList function correct?

Comment: @Nithur Yes it is